# Extract text from pdf and word files

Tags: c#, pdf, ms-word

How can I extract text from pdf or word files (remove bold, images, and other rich text formatting media) in C#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the filters designed for / used by the indexing service. They're designed to extract the plain text out of various documents, which is useful for searching inside a document. You can use it for Office files, PDFs, HTML and so on, basically any file type that has a filter. The only downside is that you have to install these filters on the server, so if you don't have direct access to the server this may not be possible. Some filters come pre-installed with Windows, but some, like PDF, you have to install yourself. For a C# implementation check out this article: [Using IFilter in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/IFilter.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

## PDF:

You have various options.

**pdftotext:**
Download the [XPDF utilities](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html). In the .zip file there are various commandline utilities. One is `pdftotext(.exe)`. It can extract all text content from a well-behaving PDF file. Type `pdftotext -help` to learn about some if its commandline parameters.

**Ghostscript:**
Install the [latest version of Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/releases/) (v.8.71). Ghostscript is a PostScript- and PDF-interpreter. You can use it to extract text from a PDF as well:

```
gswin32c.exe ^
 -q ^
 -sFONTPATH=c:/windows/fonts ^
 -dNODISPLAY ^
 -dSAFER ^
 -dDELAYBIND ^
 -dWRITESYSTEMDICT ^
 -dSIMPLE ^
 -f ps2ascii.ps ^
 -dFirstPage=3 ^
 -dLastPage=7 ^
 input.pdf ^
 -dQUIET
```

This will output text contained on pages 3-7 of `input.pdf` to stdout. You can redirect this to a file by appending `> /path/to/output.txt` to the command. (Check to make sure that the PostScript utility program `ps2ascii.ps` is present in your Ghostscript's `lib` subdirectory.)

If you omit the `-dSIMPLE` parameter, the text output will be guessing line breaks and word spacings. For details look at the comments inside the `ps2ascii.ps` file itself. You can even replace that param with `-dCOMPLEX` for gaining additional text formatting info.

Answer (score 0):

For PDF did you take a look at [TallPDF](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/showcase/TallComponents.aspx)

Also check this one: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/PDF_to_TEXT.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use Word object model, it's the only reliable way since Word format is not open and vary from version to version.

Comment: But how though? This is a useless response without a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at PDFBox.  Here is a link to a Code Project page showing you how to use it in C# as well as other useful comments.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/pdf2text.aspx

As for Word the suggestion of using the Word Object model is probably the most accurate.

Answer (score 0):

[Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) can be used to extract text from PDF files.

The library can [extract plain text and text with formatting](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/pdf-text/extract). Also, a [collection of words](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Text/ExtractTextByWords) or characters with bounding rectangles can be retrieved using library's API.

Disclaimer: I work for the vendor of the library.